# Session is regenerate on page reload in remote server working fine in local server

Tags: php, session

I am having session issue in remote server, at first session gets initialized and stored successfully with values in it but new empty session file is generated on page reload.

Everything is working fine in local server.

here is how I am checking for session.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
echo 'Session id = '.session_id();
```

my remote php.ini file has these values.

```
engine = On
output_buffering = On
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 1024M
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
session.save_path = /home4/user/sess
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /home4/user/sess.cookie
session.cookie_domain =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 20
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = 1
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_expire = 60
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.use_trans_sid = 0
```

I have seen lot of related answers here but none seems to work for me.

Please see and suggest any possible way to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem should be the domain name as i can read from your writting. Check out where you are deploying to your code, like (if domain name has got underscores and etc

Comment: @Mubo I am checking at this address `http://www.example.com/test.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem is with cookie path and missing of cookie domain

```
session.cookie_path = /home4/user/sess.cookie
session.cookie_domain =
```

use instead your domain name and use `/` as path

```
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain = yourdomainname.com
```

Comment: wow it's working now, I made this change only `session.cookie_domain = yourdomainname.com` and its working. do I need to make this change too `session.cookie_path = /`

Comment: if you will use `session.cookie_path = /` the cookie can be read from any path on your domain and session can de used anywhere in your domain